# how to use estimatedDocumentCount of mongoose in nestJs?

Tags: nestjs, mongoose-schema

I have a problem, I'm trying to refactor my nodeJs server with **nestJs**.

The idea here is to check when starting the server if the 'Roles' collection already exists and contains entries, if not, we generate the roles in the mongoDB collection.

I have this folder stucture : mongoose schemas in a 'models' folder and an index.js that imports them:

[image]

> ./models/role.model.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Role = mongoose.model(
  "Role",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
  })
);
module.exports = Role;
```

> ./models/index.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = {};
db.mongoose = mongoose;
db.user = require("./user.model");
db.role = require("./role.model");
db.ROLES = ["user", "admin", "moderator"];
module.exports = db;
```

and then, in server.js, i import index.js as db then i define Role as db.role and i use an init function with 'Role.estimatedDocumentCount' to count the number of documents and do some logic:

> ./server.js

```
const db = require("./models");
const Role = db.role;
[...]
function init() {
  Role.estimatedDocumentCount((err, count) => {
    if (!err && count === 0) {
      new Role({
        name: "user"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }
        console.log("added 'user' to roles collection");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

It's working super fine on my **nodeJs server**, but problems comes with the new **nestJs server**, basically, i think it's a *type issue*, and i'm not sure if my method is legit in a nestjs environement, assuming i'm an absolute begginer in it... This is what i tried:

> ./schemas/role.schema.ts

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type RoleDocument = Role & Document;

@Schema()
export class Role {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
}

export const RoleSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Role);
```

> ./schemas/index.ts

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { User } from './user.schema'
import { Role } from './role.schema'

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
export const db = {
  mongoose: mongoose,
  user: User,
  role: Role,
  ROLES: ["user", "admin", "moderator"]
};
```

> ./main.ts

```
[...]
import { db } from './auth/schemas';
const Role = db.role;
[...]
function init() {
  Role.estimatedDocumentCount((err, count) => {
    if (!err && count === 0) {
      new Role({
        name: "user"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }
        console.log("added 'user' to roles collection");
      });

    }
  });
}
```

But it's not working, i get this error:

[image]

And when i check the type on the **nodeJs server** i have this:

[image]

But on **nestJs server** i get another type, this is why i think my issue comes from type, or maybe that method can't work the same way than on nodeJs for some reason...

[image]

EDIT: i also tried getting directly the roleSchema in my main.ts file, i'm getting a more interesting type, but it's not working either:

```
import { RoleSchema } from './auth/schemas/role.schema';
function init() {
  RoleSchema.estimatedDocumentCount((err, count) => {
    if (!err && count === 0) {
      new Role({
        name: "user"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }
        console.log("added 'user' to roles collection");
      });

    }
  });
}
```

[image]

EDIT2: reply to gianfranco

> auth.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtStrategy } from './strategies/jwt.strategy';
import { LocalStrategy } from './strategies/local.strategy';

import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserSchema } from './schemas/user.schema';
import { RoleSchema } from './schemas/role.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema },{ name: 'Role', schema: RoleSchema}]),
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

> auth.controller.ts

```
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  Post,
  Get,
  Res,
  Request,
  UseGuards,
  ValidationPipe,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import express, { Response } from 'express';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthCredentialsDto } from './dto/auth-credentials.dto';
import { LocalAuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from './guards/jwt-auth.guard';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  @Post('signup')
  async signUp(
    @Body(ValidationPipe) authCredentialsDto: AuthCredentialsDto,
  ): Promise<void> {
    return await this.authService.signUp(authCredentialsDto);
  }

  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('signin')
  async signIn(@Request() req) {
    return this.authService.signIn(req.user);
  }

  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Get('me')
  getMe(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: what's in the module.ts and controller.ts? you can check this example and see if there's something in yours that's missing https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/06-mongoose/src/cats

Comment: I found a solution by creating a nest service. I'll post a PR

Answer (score 0):

The key was to implement the logic in auth.service.ts instead of setting it in main.ts.Thanks for your help!